# Is it possible to access Sonar's blame info? (sonar-scm-activity)

Tags: sonarqube

I need to know where the blame information is stored in Sonar so I can use it to run metrics on a specific developer. Simply put, is it even possible to access it?

Answer (score 0):

The SCM Activity Plugin feeds the following metrics:

- authors_by_line
- revisions_by_line
- last_commit_datetimes_by_line